# can't create django project using Windows command prompt

Tags: python, django

if i run

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

django-admin.py  (which is located in `C:\python27\scripts/django-admin.py`) will open in a file editor (now it opens in python ide, but in the past i had pype so it would open in pype) so the file  opens:

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

i see no output in the command prompt at all, so lets say i typed

```
C:\abc:>django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

when I hit enter i see `C:\abc>`

and the project will not be created using the command prompt

this issue is not new for me, i'm creating my python projects using pydev, i would love to fix this issue with the command prompt though :)

**@slugonamission**

when I run

```
pyhon django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

the output of the command prompt is

```
python: can't open 'django-admin.py' file : [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: It would be helpful to people if you made the headline reflect the specifics of the problem

Comment: you can just type django-admin.py startproject ABC or python django-admin.py startproject ABC

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think Windows supports the shebang line. Try invoking it with `python django-admin.py ...`

Comment: @Eli: use the full path, so: `python C:\python27\scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite`.

Comment: @jro can i create a batch file that would run 'python C:\python27\scripts\django-admin.py startproject' for me and then i type the name of my project and hit enter?

Comment: @Eli: yep, just add `python C:\python27\scripts\django-admin.py startproject %1` to your batch file, and call it like `startproject.bat mysite`. To do it cleanly, save it in `C:\python27\Scripts`, and add that folder to your path variable. Or when lazy, just save it in `C:\python27` and it'll work right away.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using python 2.7 , django 1.7 in windows7.

WAY-1:

1) Go to `C:\Python27\Scripts` (or your installation directory)

2) open `cmd` and enter `python django-admin-script.py startproject ProjectName`

3)Your project folder with all necessary files ll be created there.

The problem is in windows, `django-admin.py` is supplied as `django-admin-script.py`

WAY2:

1)Open `cmd` at any location you want.

2)enter `django-admin startproject ProjectName`

3)Your project folder with all necessary files ll be created there.

Its because the .exe file is supplied.

Answer (score 5):

This often happens in Windows.

1. Open cmd at any location you want.
2. enter `django-admin startproject ProjectName` (don't add the .py extension to the admin)
3. Your project folder with all necessary files will be created there.

This is because the .exe file is supplied inside the directory.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who has this issue:

**Try taking out the '.py'**

```
django-admin startproject helloworld
```

Answer (score 2):

firstly find out where the django-admin.py is located then go to that path and then run the command django-admin.py startproject *projectName*
i hope it will help you......best luck

Answer (score -2):

Using the [Bitnami Django Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/django)

```
> cd C:\Users\user_user_name\Bitnami Django Stack projects
C:\Users\user_user_name\Bitnami Django Stack projects>
> python C:\Bitnami\djangostack-1.8.17-0\apps\django\Django-1.8.17-py2.7.egg\EGG-INFO\scripts\django-admin.py --version
> python C:\Bitnami\djangostack-1.8.17-0\apps\django\Django-1.8.17-py2.7.egg\EGG-INFO\scripts\django-admin.py startproject projectname
```

That works for me.